# Null safe boolean expression evaluation

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

Is there a Null and NullPointer safe way to evaluate boolean expressions.

Here's an example from our codebase -

```
private boolean serviceReturnedSuccess(Response response) {
    boolean isSuccess = true;
    if (response.hasMetadata()) {
        Metadata responseMetadata = response.getMetadata();
        if (responseMetadata.hasReturnCode()) {
            if (responseMetadata.getReturnCode() != 0) {
                isSuccess = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return isSuccess;
}
```

What I would like to write is -

```
private boolean serviceReturnedSuccess(Response response) {
    return NullSafeBooleanEvaluator.valueOf(response.getMetadata().getReturnCode() != 0);
}
```

I couldn't find something that does this out of the box when I looked at `BooleanUtils` in `apache commons` or in `Guava's` [common object utils](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CommonObjectUtilitiesExplained).

I am ideally looking for an implementation in one of the standard libraries, otherwise I'm looking for a generic way to implement this.

Comment: There's the new Optional type in Java 8 which gives a better alternative to null checks, however not sure if it will work in case with nested nullable references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can't be a `NullSafeBooleanEvaluator.valueOf(response.getMetadata().getReturnCode() != 0)` since the argument expression must be evaluated before it is passed to `NullSafeBooleanEvaluator.valueOf()`. The closest solution would be

```
private boolean serviceReturnedSuccess(Response response) {
    try {
        return response.getMetadata().getReturnCode() != 0;
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

which of course has some code smell.

As Egor already commented Java 8 introduced the new Optional class for such problems (see also this informative [article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html)):

But I am not convinced that it leads to readable code:

```
if (response.flatMap(Response::getMetadata).map(MetaData::getReturnCode).orElse(0) != 0)
```

(probably lot of errors in this code, but you get the idea).

The above article also mentions Groovy's *safe navigation operator* ? which allows for a very elegant expression:

```
 if (response.getMetaData()?.getResponseCode()? != 0)
```

(again not tested).
But Java is not Groovy, so I think your current code is probably the optimum if you don't want/can't use Optionals.

Comment: Thanks, these objects are vended by another team so I can't use optional here. Hopefully something like this will be possible in later versions of java.